# How can a glider pilot add sport pilot privileges?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, light-sport-aircraft

If I understand the rules correctly, if one already has a Private Pilot rating, then one has Sport Pilot privileges but will need an endorsement for a new category/class of aircraft. What if one has a Private Glider rating? Would that person be able to fly a Sport Pilot power aircraft with just an endorsement?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can we assume that you're asking about FAA regulations?

Comment: Yes. My situation is that I have a Private Pilot - Glider certificate (over 3000 hours). Have held a class III medical in the past and have some solo hours in single engine aircraft (J3 Cub, C-140, C-150/152, C-175). Never completed the Private Pilot  - airplane due to life/job/$$$). I qualify for Basic Med and am working on the Private Pilot - airplane cert. I just bought a TL-2000 Sting light sport plane. Several people told me I should be able to get the Sport Pilot -airplane privileges through the endorsement process rather than having to take the written exam.

Comment: Based on your current situation, the answer is yes with caveats. You only need one endorsement every 90 days from your CFI to fly solo in your TL-2000. As a matter of fact, the endorsement is make and model specific. So, your CFI could endorse any model in which you are trained. There will be limits on the operations you may fly. One big limitation would be that you can not fly passengers as PIC.

Comment: By the way, you only need to pass the written knowledge exam once in your life for each Pilot Certificate regardless of how many Category, Class, and Type ratings that you get. You pass a different knowledge test for an instrument rating. You may have to pass different Practical Exam Checkrides for different Cat, Class & Types. The only exception to this is the ATP. You need a written to add Category and Class ratings for ATP.

Comment: If you have a PPL certificate for Single Engine Land you can fly any of the Single Engine Land Sport Aircraft since they are in the same category and class. You do not need any additional endorsements or ratings. It woud be a good idea to get training in the specific aircraft singe they may handle slightly differently than what you are used to  because of their smaler size and weight.

Comment: @JScarry - That is somewhat correct for ASEL. Although, not every ASEL would qualify for your statement. An ASEL may require a type rating to operate. The same is true for high powered, complex, and tail wheel ASELs. They would require a specific endorsement to operate. Although, there wouldn’t be any complex nor high powered LSAs. What if the private pilot does not have a powered aircraft category and class rating as is the case for the glider pilot who originally posted the question?

Comment: @DeanF. If you have an ASEL PPL then you *automatically* qualify to fly single-engine land sport pilot. If you have additional endorsements or type ratings, that’s fine but it doesn’t apply to sport pilots since —by definition—none of the sport planes are complex or high performance. A glider pilot does not have an ASEL PPL certificate so cannot fly a sport plane.

Comment: @JScarry - My thoughts exactly. Although, I don’t see a way around the taildragger endorsement even in an LSA. With as many flight hours as the glider pilot who posted the question has, hopefully he has finished his PPL-ASEL under Basic Med by now.

Comment: @DeanF. I had forgotten that there are taildraggers that qualify under the sport pilot rules. You would need an endorsement to fly them.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. You can get student pilot privileges with only a CFI endorsement for a new Category and Class. You would not have Sport Pilot privileges, though. The regs for Sport Pilot certificate holders would be that you need endorsements from two different CFIs and file an application with the FAA for each Category and Class.

Although 61.303 and 61.321 can be confusing, they both make mention of category and class. A sport cert does not have Cat & Class. For Sport Pilot privileges you have to have a training endorsement from one instructor and a proficiency check endorsement from a second instructor before the FAA will issue you a Cat & Class endorsement.

> **61.321 How do I obtain privileges to operate an additional category or class of light-sport aircraft?**
>
> If you hold a sport pilot certificate and seek to operate an additional category or class of light-sport aircraft, you must—
>
> (a) Receive a logbook endorsement from the authorized instructor who trained you on the applicable aeronautical knowledge areas specified in §61.309 and areas of operation specified in §61.311. The endorsement certifies you have met the aeronautical knowledge and flight proficiency requirements for the additional light-sport aircraft privilege you seek;
>
> (b) Successfully complete a proficiency check from an authorized instructor other than the instructor who trained you on the aeronautical knowledge areas and areas of operation specified in §§61.309 and 61.311 for the additional light-sport aircraft privilege you seek;
>
> (c) Complete an application for those privileges on a form and in a manner acceptable to the FAA and present this application to the authorized instructor who conducted the proficiency check specified in paragraph (b) of this section; and
>
> (d) Receive a logbook endorsement from the instructor who conducted the proficiency check specified in paragraph (b) of this section certifying you are proficient in the applicable areas of operation and aeronautical knowledge areas, and that you are authorized for the additional category and class light-sport aircraft privilege.

Private, Sport, Recreational, Commercial, etc. are all separate certificates. You can have multiple category and class ratings on each. If you have a Private certificate already, you will not need to get another certificate for any further non-commercial privileges. All you need to add a different Category or Class is an endorsement showing appropriate training and a Checkride. You will retain Private Privelages for any Category and Class listed on your certificate. Glider is a separate Category to any powered aircraft.

> **61.63 Additional aircraft ratings (other than for ratings at the airline transport pilot certification level).**
>
> (a) General. For an additional aircraft rating on a pilot certificate, other than for an airline transport pilot certificate, a person must meet the requirements of this section appropriate to the additional aircraft rating sought.
>
> (b) Additional aircraft category rating. A person who applies to add a category rating to a pilot certificate:
>
> (1) Must complete the training and have the applicable aeronautical experience.
>
> (2) Must have a logbook or training record endorsement from an authorized instructor attesting that the person was found competent in the appropriate aeronautical knowledge areas and proficient in the appropriate areas of operation.
>
> (3) Must pass the practical test.
>
> (4) Need not take an additional knowledge test, provided the applicant holds an airplane, rotorcraft, powered-lift, weight-shift-control aircraft, powered parachute, or airship rating at that pilot certificate level.
>
> (c) Additional aircraft class rating. A person who applies for an additional class rating on a pilot certificate:
>
> (1) Must have a logbook or training record endorsement from an authorized instructor attesting that the person was found competent in the appropriate aeronautical knowledge areas and proficient in the appropriate areas of operation.
>
> (2) Must pass the practical test.
>
> (3) Need not meet the specified training time requirements prescribed by this part that apply to the pilot certificate for the aircraft class rating sought; unless, the person only holds a lighter-than-air category rating with a balloon class rating and is seeking an airship class rating, then that person must receive the specified training time requirements and possess the appropriate aeronautical experience.
>
> (4) Need not take an additional knowledge test, provided the applicant holds an airplane, rotorcraft, powered-lift, weight-shift-control aircraft, powered parachute, or airship rating at that pilot certificate level.

**For instance, I have a Private Cert for Airplane Single Engine Land. I also have Rotorcraft Helicopter hours. I can not solo a helicopter without an endorsement from my instructor. Essentially, giving me Student Pilot privileges for helicopters without a student pilot license (minus the Class B restriction). I would need a Checkride to add Rotorcraft Helicopter to my Private Cert.**

Comment: I don't believe this is completely accurate in the case of sport pilots. AFAIK, categories and classes don't apply directly to sport pilots. See 61.303, which is probably what the OP is looking for. And all of this assumes the OP is indeed asking about the US, of course.

Comment: @Pondlife - I figured as much. Although 61.303 and 61.321 can be confusing, they both make mention of category and class. A sport cert does not have Cat & Class. You have to have an endorsement from one instructor and a proficiency check from a second before the FAA will issue you a Cat & Class endorsement.

Comment: @Pondlife - if you only have a Private cert with only a glider rating, chances are that you do not have a Med Cert. It is not required. In which case, you only have privileges for gliders and balloons of a sport cert. Otherwise, you have to follow the process in the pre ious comment

Comment: I agree, sport pilot stuff is typically a bit messy - or less understood! - than the rest. I was mostly commenting on the wording "You can have multiple category and class ratings on each", which isn't accurate for RP or SP, at least as far as I know. As always, I'm completely prepared to be wrong :-)